# Parse and Core data relation and pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

i am trying to sync my project to parse. right now i am saving my data in core data. i have 2 kind of entities: Night and Session. it's look like this: Night have many session and session have one night.
[image]

when i want to add session to night i create or fetch night and add new session. this way i can get from my night all the session and the opposite way. in order to uploading it to parse i have added in the "Session" table "Night" column ( of type Pointer ) and in "Night" table i added "Sessions" column ( of type relation ) this is how it's look like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

i already succeeded to sync all the record from parse to Core data EXCEPT the relation and Pointers.
my problem is that the only solution for that ( insert this relation into core data ) is to create new night ( i mean create instance ) and create new sessions and add them like this:

```
-(void)addSession:(Session *)session toNight:(Night *)night {
    if (session && night) {
        NSMutableSet * sessionSet = [night.sessions mutableCopy];
        [sessionSet addObject:session];
        night.sessions = sessionSet;
    }
}
```

So my Question is:

1. this is the only way? create instance and add them?
2. when i add Session to Night or when i add Night to session, why it's not shown in the DB table. i can not see this connection. ( like i see in parse ,relation and pointers)
3. when i get the Relation from parse it's look like this:

> sessions =     {
>           "__type" = Relation;
>           className = Session;
>       };

what i can do with that?

Thanks for reading this long Question and i hope i was clear :)

BTW: i follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2) and they do not have relation and pointers.

**Updatde**
i am using Parse Rest Clint API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is the only way? create instance and add them?

yes. either you create a `night` object and set its `sessions` property; or you create a `session` object and set its `night` property. (provided you have defined and inverse in your core data model).

> when i add Session to Night or when i add Night to session, why it's not shown in the DB table. i can not see this connection. ( like i see in parse ,relation and pointers)

this is not clear to me. What would you like to see in the DB table? if you add a bunch of `sessions` to a `night`, or you set the `night` property on `session` object, then when you inspect those object (reap. `night` - `session`) you can access the properties and should show the right value...

> when i get the Relation from parse it's look like this:

In Parse, you do not need to model *both* the Pointer and the Relation (as it happens in Core Data where you have a relation and its inverse).

You just need the pointer for a one to many relationship. Parse relations are used from many to many relationships.

So, what you should to store all of the sessions in Parse is fetching them through a query like:

```
PFObject* night ...
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Sessions"];
[query whereKey:@"night" equalTo:night];
```

then `[query findObjects...]` will give you an array of sessions you can add in a go to your Night Core Data object. (so, no need to call multiple time `addSession:`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using Parse Rest clint API.

Comment: well, my remark holds still even if you are using the REST API. Check https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-relational at the Relational Queries section to find the equivalent (you will need to give `night` objectId explicitly)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response :) but correct me if i'm wrong, your answer is for my third question, right? "how i get the Relation from parse?"

Comment: You are right, in my mind, the really important question was the third... :-) anyway, I added answers for the other 2 questions...

Answer (score 0):

This is just answer to my first question: i follow this [article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)  and i found this quote:

> Core Data cannot operate on data without loading the data into memory.

so i guess i solved my first question. Yes i have to load the data into my memory and then make the connection.